# how do i hyperlink a biblical text when asking questions?

Tags: support, formatting

I have been trying to hyperlink a biblical text but i have been failing to that.I have just been copying and pasting some verses.Some quotes are long so i want to use hyperlinks without copying the whole paragraph or verses.

How do i go about doing that?

Comment: `[link text](URL)` is the general way to make any link.